# Retry with condition jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi there I run into problem that if I want to run [retry](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times) with condition job keeps failing.
Heres with added condition phrase:

```
WorkflowScript: 56: Invalid parameter "conditions", did you mean "count"? @ line 56, column 27.
       retry(count: 120, conditions: !Jenkins.instance.getItem('secret-name-of-job').getLastBuild().getExecution().isComplete()) {
                         ^
```

also while I was trying to do not add conditions explicitly another error appear

```
WorkflowScript: 56: Arguments to "retry" must be explicitly named. @ line 56, column 9.
       retry(count: 120, !Jenkins.instance.getItem('secret-name-of-job').getLastBuild().getExecution().isComplete()) {
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?
Code from jenkinsfile:

```
  steps {
    retry(count: 120, conditions: !Jenkins.instance.getItem('secret-name-of-job').getLastBuild().getExecution().isComplete()) {
      echo "Sleeping for 1 minute since e2e build is running..."
      sleep(time: 1, unit: 'MINUTES')
  } more code }
```

**EDIT**
With help of @ycr and few tries I was able to achieve waiting until other job is finished

Code:

```
      script {
        retry(count: 120) {
          if (Jenkins.instance.getItem('magic-secret-job').getLastBuild().getExecution().isComplete() == false) {
            echo "Waiting since e2e build is running..."
            sleep(time: 1, unit: "MINUTES")
            throw new Error('e2e is still running')
          }
        } some_other_code }
```

Conslusions:

- retry needs to be under script if you want to use if/loops
- If you create condition first time, it mayfail because you need to approve methods in "In-process Script Approval" section
- You need to throw exception to trigger retry once more time
- Still not sure how `conditions` works, as @ycr mentioned it has to be some sort of extension of `ErrorCondition`

Comment: After reading your update it seems you should be using https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#waituntil-wait-for-condition instead of retry.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `conditions` accepts a list of objects that implements ErrorCondition. Check [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/RetryStepExecution.java#L22).

```
private transient final @CheckForNull List<ErrorCondition> conditions;
```

As far as I observed there are few pre implemented ErrorConditions you can use. (`SynchronousResumeNotSupportedErrorCondition`, `AgentErrorCondition`, `KubernetesAgentErrorCondition` etc.), So you have to use one of these or  you may have to implement a custom condition yourself and add it to the runtime extending `ErrorCondition`.

Having said that, here is how you can get what you need without conditions. Just add a `try-catch` around your execution and handle the error in `catch` block. Check the following.

```
retry(count: 3) {
    try {
        echo "Sleeping for 1 minute since e2e build is running..."
        sleep(time: 5, unit: 'SECONDS')
        
    } catch(e) {
        if(Jenkins.instance.getItem('test').getLastBuild().getExecution().isComplete()) {
            // Let's error out the the condition is true which will trigger a retry
            throw e
        }
        echo "Condition failed, means no retry, so complete the Job" 
    }
  
}
```